# Splitting a sentence to meaningful parts

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I have the following sentence

```
query = u'tell me about people in konoha who have wind style chakra and are above jonin level'
```

I want to split the above sentence into the following three parts

```
[
 "tell me about people in konoha",
 "who have wind style chakra",
 "and are above jonin level"
]
```

I have looked into sent tokenizers in **spacy** and **nltk**, but they are not giving me the desired results.

I am just a beginner in nlp and machine learning and have very limited knowledge so far. It would be awesome if you could direct me to some techniques or available packages through which I could achieve the above results.

**EDIT**

I'll be having question-like queries like the one above where I would be asking for details about the subject based on some constraints

In the above query the subject was **people in Konoha** and the constraints are **have wind style chakra** and **above jonin level**

I want to extract such relationships from similar queries.

Comment: I guess what you are doing as seen by your output can be done using indexing as such

Comment: Could you explain on that please.

Comment: Your sentence sounds perfectly fine, You need to explain a bit more so that anyone can help you..

Comment: Query answering does not involve clause segmentation as a preprocessing step. I suggest reading the literature if that is your ultimate goal: https://github.com/dapurv5/awesome-question-answering

Comment: I intend to convert the above query into a database query where I would be extracting the info stored in the db about the subject with constraints applied as filters.

Comment: When down-voting please do specify the reason.. it would help to rectify any mistakes if present in future posts.

Answer (score 7):

You are looking to create a  [parse tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parse_tree) to find multi-token clauses.

Here is code to generate a parse tree:

```
import spacy
from nltk import Tree

nlp = spacy.load('en')

def to_nltk_tree(node):
    if node.n_lefts + node.n_rights > 0:
        return Tree(node.orth_, [to_nltk_tree(child) for child in node.children])
    else:
        return node.orth_

query = u'tell me about people in konoha who have wind style chakra and are above jonin level'
doc = nlp(query)
[to_nltk_tree(sent.root).pretty_print() for sent in doc.sents]
```

Output:

```
    tell                          
  ____|______                       
 |         about                   
 |           |                      
 |         people                  
 |     ______|_____                 
 |    |           have             
 |    |       _____|____________    
 |    |      |     |     |     are 
 |    |      |     |     |      |   
 |    |      |     |   chakra above
 |    |      |     |     |      |   
 |    in     |     |   style  level
 |    |      |     |     |      |   
 me konoha  who   and   wind  jonin
```

From that parse tree, you can then select the phrases.